# Knockoutjs: How do i check if another element is clicked in my custom binding

Tags: knockout.js

I added a custom binding to an element, its job is to constantly check if an li tag has been clicked so i added an onclick listener inside it, but it does work. how come, this is my code:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.makeActive = {

    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // First get the latest data that we're bound to
        var value = valueAccessor();

        // Next, whether or not the supplied model property is observable, get its current value
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);

        $(".friend a").click(function(){
            alert("The element was clicked.");
        });


    }
};
```

is there a way i can check if an element has been clicked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missplaced your logic a  little bit.
Do not set your click listener in the update callback, it will try to register the event every time the observable attached to the element is updated. Instead register the listener in the initialize callback like so :

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.makeActive = {
     init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
         $(".friend a").on('click',function(){
            alert("The element was clicked.");
         });
     },
     update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) 
     {
     }
};
```

Now on the other hand you should bind this handler directly on the element you want to observe, so you should not have a selector in there but rather

```
 $(element).on('click',function(){
            alert("The element was clicked.");
        });
```

This will also save you from registering the handler multiple times in case you use your custom binding on more than 1 elements. Now each handler will take care of one element, instead of having a selector that could parse the same elements over and over with each call